# Constant 'soda1' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift, constants

Just a small simple code. It does run, and prints out the right results, but I am getting the error: Constant 'soda1' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected. Not sure how to fix it. 
Trying to code a simple program to output the price of a liter of soda.

```
func sodaoffer(type: String, price: Double, size: Double, amount: Double = 1) {
    let priceL = price / (size * amount)
    print("\(type) costs \(priceL) per liter")
}

let soda1 = sodaoffer(type: "Cola", price: 15, size: 1.5)
let soda2 = sodaoffer(type: "Fanta", price: 50, size: 0.5, amount: 4)
let soda3 = sodaoffer(type: "Faxe Kondi", price: 25, size: 2)
```

Comment: What do you *expect* that `let soda1 = sodaoffer(...)` does?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a function that returns () or Void (this means nothing) to a variable.

Try to return something:

```
func makeSodaOfferString(type: String, price: Double, size: Double, amount: Double = 1) -> String {
    let priceL = price / (size * amount)
    return "\(type) costs \(priceL) per liter)"
}

let sodaOffer1 = makeSodaOfferString(type: "Cola", price: 15, size: 1.5)
let sodaOffer2 = makeSodaOfferString(type: "Fanta", price: 50, size: 0.5, amount: 4)
let sodaOffer3 = makeSodaOfferString(type: "Faxe Kondi", price: 25, size: 2)

print(sodaOffer1)
print(sodaOffer2)
print(sodaOffer3)
```